# Laravel route translation issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes

It is a very strange situation. Some of my routes doesn't want to be translated. I am using the Laravel mcamara/laravel-localization package.

The routes are translated as described in the documentation. 
On my website I have a flag for each translation to change the language. By hover on the flags, it changes only the language, but does not translate the route. The strange thing, is that for some routes it works, but for some not and I cannot find out what is the logic.

For example I have one controller for displaying articles. Here are the routes:

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.artciles').'/{id}/{slug}.html', ['as' => 'strategy.show', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@show']);
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.artciles').'/{category}.html', ['as' => 'strategy.category', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@category']);
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.artciles').'.html', ['as' => 'strategy.index', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@index']);
```

Here it fails to translate the routes?

By hovering I see just:

`en/articles.html`, `de/articles.html` instead of `en/articles.html` `de/artikel.html`.

Comment: Dont you have an typo in `LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.artciles')`? Didn't you mean 'routes.articles' ?

Comment: unfortunately not. in the lang/routes.php it was also the same typo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Here it is for somebody who has similar problem:

in Http/routes.php the code must be without the parameters:

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.article'), ['as' => 'strategy.show', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@show'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.article_cat'), ['as' => 'strategy.category', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@category']);
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.articles'), ['as' => 'strategy.index', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@index']);
```

And in the lang/routes.php you can include the parameters like this:

```
'articles' => 'help.html',
'article' => 'help/{id}/{slug}.html',
'article_cat' => 'help/{category}.html',
```